# How does the third parameter of the sort function works?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am having problems understanding how to make functions to sort variables in C++.

For example, using this function:

```
sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comp)
```

Why if I use the following comp function, the sort function makes the vector inversed?

```
bool comp (int i, int j) { 
    return true; 
}
```

Why if I use the following comp function, the sort function orders the vector in decreasing order?

```
bool comp (int i, int j) { 
    return i > j; 
}
```

Comment: if you just return `true` then there is no sorting - every value is the same as every other value, so any order is legal.

Comment: You should check that, because it actually reverses the vector. If I have 4 1 8 10 and sort that I get 10 8 1 4

Comment: It's undefined behavior. It's not a valid comparator.

Comment: As I said, any order is valid - the fact that it reverses the order may give you a hint about how the sort is implemented.

Comment: @John3136: `return false;` would be a valid implementation, not `return true;` (as `comp(i, i)` should be `false`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't say it was a valid comparator, I said that any possible ordering of the array is a valid result from the given comparator.

Answer (score 2):

comp is a binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.

You can refer to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort)

Answer (score -1):

> Why if I use the following comp function, the sort function makes the vector inversed?
>
> `bool comp (int i, int j) { 
>       return true; 
>   }`

Ideally the above code should not compile because you are not making use of the arguments passed to comp function.

Coming to your question, the third argument in std::sort provides a way to supply custom comparator so that the supplied comparator will be called to compare elements of the vector while sorting.

```
return i > j;
```

When the above is used, the comparator returns true only when the first item is greater than the second item. When the comparator returns true, the sort function takes action to place the element `i` before element `j`. Hence you see the vector sorted in decreasing order.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code that makes it not compilable. It must compile successfully with some warnings (if enabled)

Comment: Yes it may compile with warning, but why promote such kind of a behavior.

Comment: where did I say that it's should be done like that? What I'm saying is that your statement "Ideally the above code should not compile" is completely wrong